# Anyone know of an MPD client that stores ratings in the MPD database

Tags: music, rating

Is there an existing MPD client which stores rating information in the MPD database. Plugins are acceptable.

**EDIT**
It was pointed out in the comments that it was not obvious what MPD is.

MPD (https://www.musicpd.org/) is a music player that runs as a background process (usually on *nix). A MPD Client is a program that connects to MPD over the network to provide a user interface for MPD, there are clients for all major operating systems inkluding smartphones.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I break some rule or did you just not like the question?

Comment: Maybe a link to MPD? Or some explanation of what is is?  Which operating system? Free, or do oyu have a budget? Any must have features? Then more info you give, the more help we can give you. Please read [ask] (I did not downvote you)

Comment: Edited my post to provide an explanation about what MPD is as suggested by Mawg. (thanks for the tip)

Comment: +1 for the update. Sounds like maybe you want to use the [tag:linux] tag? Maybe also [tag:gratis]?

Comment: No the linux tag would be misleading, most likely i will run the client on several different operating systems if possible.

Regarding gratis, while preferable I might consider paying if the price is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

mpd has a feature to have a sticker database. A sticker database allows you to add details which the mpd database doesn't have. Just search for sticker in the online documentation for mpd. To enable the sticker database you require the entry

sticker_file                     "/var/lib/mpd/sticker.db"

This should be a sqlite database. The schema of this database is upto you.
There are two players I know of that exploit the sticker functionality.
[Cantata](https://github.com/CDrummond/cantata) a graphical client and [myMPD](https://github.com/jcorporation/myMPD) a web based client.

Cantata allows you to rate a song with a 5 star scheme. This rating is stored in the sticker database
myMPD allows you to rate a song as Thumbs up, Thumbs Down or neutral. This is stored in the sticker database.